# React Native set a opacity to View will affect the child view (NO RGBA !!!!)

Tags: react-native, view

I set an opacity to a View, and then found that the child view also have an opacity. How to avoid this problem and set each other?

I searched the Internet for some answers. The unified saying is to set RGBA (XX, XX, XX, XX) to achieve the change of transparency.

But this method is no cure, and if my father views are gradual color of the react-native-linear-gradient library or other parent components that can't set RGBA, it is not possible to set the transparency through RGBA, then how should it be solved in this case? Solving?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `backgroundColor` property, like this:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(206, 88, 71, 0.7)'
```

I used this to make a view with alpha 0.7 background color, and the `<Text>` inside will not get the alpha property from the `<View>`

Comment: Yeah,I kown using `rgba` works, but what I really asked is whether have some other solutions.

Comment: Not an option when trying to animate using the native driver

Answer (score 0):

Set the backgroundColor of your non-transparent child element using rgb(...), NOT rgba(...)